# Mapping LDAP groups with Jboss Fuse 6.2.1 roles

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I am implementing LDAP security in Jboss Fuse 6.2.1.
My confusion is about how to map 7 roles in Jboss Fuse 6.2.1 with LDAP group.

Comment: What have you tried so far.  Have you used `role.base.dn` of the `org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule`?

Comment: yes, the role.base.dn will only return the group defined in ldap.
my query is, how to map the group from ldap to jboss fuse role.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the role mapping param and define the groups configured equal to the rolename..it should be as below.

role.mapping=JBossAdmin=admin;JBossMonitor=Monitor,viewer

--seshadri

Comment: Thanks.. i tried it but i had to override methods of LDAPLoginModule in order to make it work.
Is that the correct way or it should work without that?

Comment: It should work without override default login module (zookeeper login Module), in our project we use to maintain 2 modules as:Zookeeper login module(Default admin login), LDAP Module.